# How to JSON in Fetch()

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I can't seem to get the link I found on the assigned site to respond to the fetch command.

Here's the top line of what I'm starting with (using Seattle's lat and long because I thought that might work):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="place">Enter a City Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="place">
 <button id="get-data-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
 <script src="weather.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const getDataButton = document.getElementById("get-data-button");
getDataButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
 console.log(fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=47.6&lon=-122.3&appid={secret}"))
 .then(response => response.json());
 //.then(data => {

 displayJson = (json) => console.log(json);
```

Comment: Is there an error in your browser console? You don't seem to be calling `displayJson`; is that where your problem is?

Comment: "Invalid API key. Please see https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."

Comment: The console isn't displaying any errors. It WAS before I commented out the second .then, I assumed because there was no data being read the promise didn't serve any purpose and got mad.

Comment: Thank you! I did just create the API key. I'll give it a few hours then and see if it changes. Does the link look mostly correct? And the use of json in the code? I've been making guesses based on what I've learned so far!

Comment: Your `fetch` is wrapped in `console.log()`, which doesn't return anything and therefore doesn't have a response for your `then()`

Comment: @mykaf I see, so since I didn't contain the then with the fetch it didn't display? I was trying to get it to just show me something but that makes a lot of sense why that wouldn't work!

Comment: Take the fetch call out of the console.log and log your `response` or `response.json()` from within the `then()` clause.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the brackets from your variables in the fetch call.

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=47.6&lon=-122.3&appid=etcetc

Also I'd request a new API key from the website, somone could f**k your credit card up!

Have a good one!

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if those were supposed to be included or not, I'll try it! Out of curiosity, how does access to an API key potentially affect personal information? I didn't pay for it so I would hope it's not connected to financial accounts! Thank you!

Comment: There may not be connection currently, but who knows. In any case, exposing your API key means anything anybody does will be linked to you, including using up request quotas, etc. Keep private keys private that's why they're called that.

Comment: The website states first 1000 calls a day are free, so someone could spam the API and charge stuff to your account. It could happen, best to be wary of these things. Should work with no brackets I was testing it on postman.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).